# Difference between importing a Python file and importing * of the same file

Tags: python, python-import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python import question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635017/python-import-question)

What is the difference between importing a Python file from a folder i.e:

```
from coredump.analyzer.utils import netAnalyzer
```

and importing '*' of the same file i.e:

```
from coredump.analyzer.utils.netAnalyzer import *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first import line imports the module `netAnalyzer`. That means you have to call functions as follows: `netAnalyzer.myfunction(...)`.

The second import line imports the functions into the namespace: this means you can call `myfunction(...)` without mentioning the module name.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you risk to mess up with the namespace if you use the second import and you don't know what you are doing (since you might not be aware that the module implements functions or variables with the same name of some that you might have already implemented in your code, and that will be overwritten)