# Difference between importing file and variable

Tags: python

in questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635017/from-x-import-y-vs-from-x-y-import) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051412/difference-between-importing-a-python-file-and-importing-of-the-same-file), it is stated that the difference between using
`import file_a`
and
`from file_a import func_a`
is just that I need to call `file_a.func_a()` in the first case and `func_a()` in the second when running `func_a()`. When working with a script, I however experienced a curious behaviour. A simplified example below:

```
# file_a.py
import file_b, file_c

print(file_c.test_var)
file_b.print_var()
file_c.set_var()
print(file_c.test_var)
file_b.print_var()

# file_b.py
from file_c import test_var

def print_var():
    print(test_var)

# file_c.py
test_var = 'old'


def set_var():
    global test_var
    test_var = 'changed'
```

When I run `file_a`, I would have expected the following output:

```
old
old
changed
changed
```

but the last part is different:

```
old
old
changed
old
```

My suspicion is that the direct importing of the variable creates a copy of that variable. Can somebody point out to me what exactly is happening? Particularly: Under which conditions are new values transferred? When do I need to worry about variables being different where I would expect them to be the same? Thank you very much!

Comment: Now try with a list instead of a string (unless you've already guessed the answer for that).

Comment: Note: technically, you import a *module*, not a file. 95% of the time, modules correspond to files, but it doesn't have to be the case.

Comment: Life gets even more interesting if you move the `from file_c import test_var` line *into* the `print_var()` function, above the `print(test_var)` line.

Comment: Is the difference between the list and the string that the string is a primitive type? So would all primitive variables be imported by value while all non-primitive are imported by reference? And if so, why?

Comment: They’re *all* imported by value. The difference is that you can mutate mutable types, but can only reassign immutable types.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I would have expected they all are imported by reference instead of all by value. Python still has some surprises up its sleeve for me it seems.